# QT - PSQL Потеряна связь

Tags: c++, linux, qt, postgresql

Здравствуйте, возникает проблема при обычном SELECT

```
SQL: SELECT ctrl_id, ctrl_node FROM list_ctrl WHERE ctrl_devnum='357803046039299'\n

QSqlError("", "QPSQL: Unable to create query", "потеряна синхронизация с сервером: получено сообщение типа \" \", длина -308675026\n()")
```

Вываливается и падает.

Comment: Предшествует ли ошибке длительное время неиспользования соединения?

Comment: Нет, возникает в различных ситуациях, на пустом месте, идут идут запросы и фигак, думал где-то накосячил, убрал весь код до селекта и на первом же тесте умерло всё. ещё переодически вылетает double free or corruption, на на том-же PSqlQuery

Comment: `double free or corruption` ... вероятно в коде где-то проблемы с памятью, и проявляется это в глюке с БД. На то он и `undefined behavior`. Попробуйте запустить под `valgrind`.

Comment: @alexolut, В коде как раз таки всё нормально и не понятно в чём проблема, обычный мультипоточный tcp сервер. Запускал, могу скинуть стек, т.к сам в этом не особо понимаю пока )

Comment: Появление упомянутых `double free or corruption` явно говорит о проблемах при работе с памятью, так что утверждать, что всё нормально - нельзя. Допускаю, что и в коде самого драйвера Sql проблема. Но наиболее вероятно, что она в пользовательской части.

Comment: @alexolut, сейчас это на самом деле просто не так принципиально, хотелось бы сначала с бд разобраться ) а потом уже весь код пересмотрю заодно научусь стеки разбирать ) Ещё бывает такое, работает работает и просто ни с того ни с чего отваливается от БД. перерыл все логи на сервере постргес не матерится, там всё хорошо.

Comment: То, что Вы считаете "проблемой с БД" может и не быть таковым. Можно испортить память в одном месте, а сломается всё в другом. Совсем не связанном.

Comment: @alexolut, в данный момент просто не вылетает эта ошибка ))) а вылетает именно с запросом...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47320/discussion-between-dmitriy-klimov-and-alexolut).